# Partition two dates by month

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to partition a range between two dates when the month of end date is different from the month of start date, using SQL in Oracle 11gXE.
For example:

---

```
SELECT ATIVOID, OSID, DT_INI, DT_FIM  
  FROM V_MTBF
 WHERE ATIVOID IN ('12345TC','TCCS011701160001');


+------------------+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|     ATIVOID      |     OSID    |       DT_INI      |      DT_FIM        |
+------------------+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| 12345TC          |  1710201409 | 20/10/17 14:09:58 | 01/12/17 09:03:52  |
| TCCS011701160001 |  1710201112 | 20/10/17 11:12:42 | 30/11/17 16:23:13  |
+------------------+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

I would like to see:

```
+------------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|     ATIVOID      |    OSID    |      DT_INI       |      DT_FIM       |
+------------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 12345TC          | 1710201409 | 20/10/17 14:09:58 | 31/10/17 23:59:59 |
| 12345TC          | 1710201409 | 01/11/17 00:00:00 | 30/11/17 23:59:59 |
| 12345TC          | 1710201409 | 01/12/17 00:00:00 | 01/12/17 09:03:52 |
| TCCS011701160001 | 1710201112 | 20/10/17 11:12:42 | 31/10/17 23:59:59 |
| TCCS011701160001 | 1710201112 | 01/11/17 00:00:00 | 30/11/17 16:23:13 |
+------------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: what do you mean partition here? your query should show too like you want.. Give the sample data.. You can use this for your formatted table https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to obtain the expected output. Maybe "partition" is not the right term, but as you can see above, I gave the sample data and I need a help to create a query that can do the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below, Replace the static values to column and table name.

```
      WITH TEMP_CTE(ATIVOID, OSID, DT_INI,DIF_M, LVL, DT_FIM)
AS
(SELECT '12345TC' AS , '1710201409' AS OSID, TO_DATE('20/10/17 14:09:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DT_INI,
       ABS(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE('20/10/17 14:09:58', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))-  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE('01/12/17 09:03:52', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))) AS DIF_M,
        1,
        TO_DATE('01/12/17 09:03:52', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) AS DT_FIM
  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT ATIVOID, OSID, ADD_MONTHS(DT_INI, 1) AS DT_INI,
  DIF_M, LVL + 1, DT_FIM FROM TEMP_CTE WHERE LVL <= DIF_M
  )
SELECT ATIVOID, OSID,
CASE WHEN LVL = 1 THEN TO_CHAR(DT_INI, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ELSE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(DT_INI, 'MM'), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') END AS DT_INI,
CASE WHEN LVL <= DIF_M THEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(LAST_DAY(DT_INI) + 1) - 1/(24*60*60), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ELSE TO_CHAR(DT_FIM, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') END AS DT_FIM FROM TEMP_CTE
```

Comment: whats the problem with this? can you please share.

Comment: Also share what you are executing if possible.

Comment: WITH TEMP_CTE(ATIVOID, OSID, DT_INI,DIF_M, LVL, DT_FIM)
AS
(SELECT ATIVOID, OSID, DT_INI,
       ABS(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DT_INI)-  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DT_FIM)) AS DIF_M,
        1,
        DT_FIM
  FROM V_MTBF
 WHERE ATIVOID IN ('TCCS011701160001')
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT ATIVOID, OSID, ADD_MONTHS(DT_INI, 1) AS DT_INI,DIF_M, LVL + 1, ADD_MONTHS(DT_FIM, 1) AS DT_FIM FROM TEMP_CTE WHERE LVL <= DIF_M
  )  
SELECT ATIVOID, OSID, DT_INI, DT_FIM FROM TEMP_CTE
ORDER BY OSID;

Comment: TCCS011701160001 1710201112 20/11/17 00:00:00,000000000 31/12/17 00:00:00,000000000
TCCS011701160001 1710201112 20/10/17 11:12:42,000000000 30/11/17 16:23:13,000000000

Comment: Is it expected output or returned by query?

Comment: it is the query output

Comment: Then its working as expected returning two rows for diff of one month, Can you please tell me the problem with it.

Comment: See the updated answer, It gives the output same as mentioned by you.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. It almost worked. Then I fixed your code and now it works very well. I'll update your code with the fix.